# Spring Security OAuth2 - Anonymous-only endpoint

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

How can I make an endpoint accessible *only to anonymous* users? I tried

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "^/users$")
    .anonymous()
```

and

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "^/users$")
    .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ANONYMOUS");
```

but I always end up getting the following message:

```
An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

In case that matters, my last rule is

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest()
    .denyAll();
```

so as to forbid access to every non-configured endpoint by default.

**Update:** Following Dave Syer's suggestion, I merged every rule in the same chain, but I keep getting the same message. These are my rules right now:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "^/users$")
    .anonymous()
    .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "^/me$")
    .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER")
    .anyRequest()
    .denyAll();
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `http.authorizeRequests()` you reset the rules, so normally you would only call it once per configuration. I think you just need to merge your anonymous rules with your `anyRequest()` on the same chain of `authorizeRequests()`.

Comment: Thanks Dave, but I keep getting the same message. Could you please take a look at the updated post?

Comment: Maybe you have to also explicitly add matchers, e.g. `http.antMatchers("/**")`.